# Plone collective.sendaspdf ignores diazo theme

Tags: plone, wkhtmltopdf, diazo

I have a plone-site where I want to use `collective.htmltopdf` based on `wkhtmltopdf` for PDF-generation.

However when I print my site, the diazo theme doesn't get applied. The header `HTTP_X_THEME_ENABLED` is correctly passed to diazo.

There is no condition in `rules.xml`. The pages in question are public. I tried HTTPS and HTTP.

Why do the diazo rules not apply to `wkhtmltopdf`?

**UPDATE I**

The above is not true, when using `wkhtmltopdf` from my workstation. Smells like routing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the way `collective.wkhtmltopdf` deals with the page source: It gets generated from a view (not via https) and looses the information about the theme there. When I quick-hack a url-source into the source, everything works as expected.

In `collective.sendaspdf-3.0-py2.7.egg/collective/sendaspdf/transforms/wk.py`

```
    # Run the wkhtmltopdf command.
    args = [wk_command,
            '--disable-javascript',
            '--encoding',
            'utf-8',
            'http://ww2.mypage.com',
            #'file://%s/%s' % (export_dir, html_filename),
            '%s/%s' % (export_dir, filename)]
```

This cries for a pull request...